# How to fix terminal python error about virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

I'm currently using mac and whenever, I'm launching the terminal it will show like code below. I tried all the method in stackoverflow but it didnt work, so I'm posting my own. Please help me to fix this. I had tried "sudo apt-get install python3-pip" or "sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper". They are all installed

**Error Message**

Last login: Tue Aug 18 22:33:59 on ttys000
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: no such file or directory: /usr/local/bin/python3
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.

**Which python command**

/usr/bin/python

**Python version command**

Python 2.7.16

**Which python3 command**

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

**Python version3 command**

Python 3.7.4

**pip3 --version command**

pip 19.3.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Could you check VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON and PATH values?

Comment: How can I check it..? plz help me. I not familiar with this...

Comment: echo $PATH $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON in the shell/terminal

Comment: I typed that and it said that

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/Users/Hans/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands /usr/local/bin/python3